# Race-condition while sending http request

Tags: race-condition, elm

I have a situation that I need to dispatch two post requests, synchronously, and the second depends on the response of the first, the problem is that the second gets sent even before the first's response is allocated, thus sending wrong information:

```
update : msg -> model -> (model, Cmd msg)
update msg m =
    case msg of

    ...

    Submit -> (m,
        send FirstResp <| post "/resource1"
            (jsonBody <| encoderX m) int)
    FirstResp (Ok x) -> ({m | pid = x},
        send SecondResp <| post "/resource2"
            (jsonBody <| encoderY m) int)

    ...
```

I tested it several times. If the server gives `3` in the first post, the `pid` gets sent as `0`, but If I submit it again, the `pid` is sent as `3` and the answer from the server, `4`, for example, is ignored.

How can I make the post to wait for the value to be allocated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As data structures in elm are immutable `{m | pid = x}` doesn't change `m` but returns a new record. So you have no updated model when you pass it to your 2nd request.

Using `{m | pid = x}` twice would get you the result you are looking for (but it's not very beautiful)

```
FirstResp (Ok x) -> ({m | pid = x},
    send SecondResp <| post "/resource2"
        (jsonBody <| encoderY {m | pid = x}) int)
```

---

You can use `let in` to store the new model in a variable before you send the request. If you modify the model now you only have to look in one place.

```
FirstResp (Ok x) -> 
    let
        newM = {m | pid = x}
    in
        (newM, send SecondResp <| post "/resource2"
        (jsonBody <| encoderY newM) int)
```

---

If you don't need the result of the first request in your model the even better solution would be to chain the requests with `Task.andThen`. With this you don't need 2 separate messages (FirstResp, SecondResp).

```
request1 m = 
    post "/resource1" (jsonBody <| encoderX m) int)
        |> Http.toTask

request2 m =
    post "/resource1" (jsonBody <| encoderX m) int)
        |> Http.toTask

Submit -> 
    ( m
    , request1 m
        |> Task.andThen request2
        |> Task.attempt Resp
    )

Resp (Ok res2) -> 
    -- res2 is the result of your request2
```

---

If you need both results you can map them into a Tuple and extract it in the update function.

```
Submit -> 
    ( m
    , request1 m
        |> Task.andThen 
            (\res1 -> request2 res1
                |> Task.map ((,) res1) 
            )
        |> Task.attempt Resp
    )

Resp (Ok (res1, res2) -> 
    -- use res1 and res2
```

---

[Elm packages - Task](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Task)